# Get the share count of my Facebook page using Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, api

> I'd like to ask how can I get the share count of a Facebook page?

I can get the number of likes on a Facebook page using the *Facebook graph API* by adding this `284018994957837?fields=fan_count` and I have read in the *Facebook graph API* docs about the fields that I could use if I will access a Facebook page but none in the docs mention about the share count of a Facebook page. Any idea will really be appreciated :-)

Comment: How are you defining share count? You can access lots of details about impressions, who created stories by interacting/sharing your page, from [page/insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#page-story-types). You can access shared posts from [ObjectsSharedPost](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/sharedposts/)

Comment: thanks for this, ill check this :) God speed.